# How to run Stata do file in Vim

Tags: vim, stata, vim-plugin

I am looking for a way to run .do file of Stata from Vim.

Here is what I have checked out so far:

1. In this link: http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/t/textEditors.html#vim, Vim functions were suggested;
2. The rundo.exe file could be downloaded from here: http://huebler.blogspot.com/2008/04/stata.html

However, after also changing the .ini files as suggested, I still cannot run the following Vim function, which is defined in _vimrc:

```
fun! RunDoLines()
    let selectedLines = getbufline('%', line("'<"), line("'>"))

    if col("'>") < strlen(getline(line("'>")))
        let selectedLines[-1] = strpart(selectedLines[-1], 0, col("'>"))
    endif
    if col("'<") != 1
        let selectedLines[0] = strpart(selectedLines[0], col("'<")-1)
    endif

    let temp = tempname() . ".do"
    call writefile(selectedLines, temp)

    " *** CHANGE PATH AND NAME TO REFLECT YOUR SETUP. USE \\ INSTEAD OF \ ***
    exec "!start C:\\Program Files\\Scripts\\rundo.exe " . temp

    " Delete the temp file after Vim closes
    au VimLeave * exe "!del -y" temp
endfun
```

As I have mapped this function to `<F9>` using: `map <F9> :<C-U>call RunDoLines() <Enter>`
, here is the error message I get when pressing `<F9>` when opening `profile.do` through Vim in Stata's home directory.

[image]

My Vim is on Github: https://github.com/llinfeng/Vim-Win; the extracted folder containing `rundo.exe` file is on my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5tneckhr1rfrp5x/AABLZ4HGElbdbIGBGrvE7Zfta

Where am I getting it wrong?

PS: the good news is, the following `Rundo()` function works well, except for one issue:

```
fun! RunIt()
    wa
    !start /min "C:\Users\Linfeng\rundo.exe" "%:p"
endfun
```

Issue: if the .do file contains an error and Stata complains about it, the `Ctrl` key (or `Alt` key) will be held down. This makes pressing `Tab` as if `Alt-Tab`, which is shifting windows. The key-lock will only be released after pressing `Ctrl` for one time.

Comment: Please clarify what "cannot run" means. Are there any error messages?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that the .ini references Stata 13, whereas the current version is 13.1 if you have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, it is my misuse of the function `RunDoLines()` that has caused the problem. The function is still compatible with Vim on Windows 8.1.

For calling this function:

1. Add `vnoremap` to the `<F9>` mapping.
2. Visually select (several) line(s).
3. Press `F9`.

***It will not work if you simply put the cursor on one line. The line has to be visually selected.*** The function needs to be filled with a "selected line", which should be visually selected as far as I am concerned. Selecting a line of code in insert mode by dragging the mouse will not generate the parameters that is needed by the function.

Stay in normal mode and press `V` to run the chunk of code!